# Could prime numbers be defined like this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, definition, conjectures

While playing with prime numbers, I found the following definition.
Let $p$ be an integer.
Then $p$ is a prime number if and only if
there is some integer $b \neq 1$ such that
$$ \frac{b^p - 1}{b - 1} $$
is also a prime number.

It is easy to show that the primality of $p$ is a necessary condition for primality of $(b^p - 1)/(b - 1)$.
I am however stuck to prove that, for given $p$, there is always at least one prime number of the form $(b^p - 1)/(b - 1)$.

Is my definition correct, and if so, how to prove the second part?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Doesn’t this require you to already know what the primes are?

Comment: It seems like this is implausible just based on a density argument. For large primes, heuristically, we shouldn't expect to see any primes of the form $(b^p-1)/(b-1)$, since the set of such numbers has very low density. It might be difficult to explicitly find a counterexample, though.

Comment: How are you going about showing that $\frac{b^p-1}{b-1}$ must be true for some $b$ given that $p$ is prime?

Comment: Using the Mathematica primality check PrimeQ I searched for prime values of $(b^{113} - 1)/(b - 1)$. The first  example I found is when $b=86$  That is 86 primality checks on increasingly large numbers when all I need do is a single prime check on $113$ using the same algorithm. Unless you can bound $b$, below which a prime must exist, when will you know when to stop checking ever higher values of $b$?

Comment: @Randall: Yes. However, this is similar to the traditional definition. You must know all primes below $p$ or at least below $\sqrt{p}$ to state the $p$ is a prime.

Comment: @MoKo19 Not sure what you are asking for. I can show that if the $(b^p-1)/(b-1)$ is prime, then the exponent $p$ must also be prime. However, I do not know how to prove that there is always at least one prime $(b^p-1)/(b-1)$ for each prime $p$.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Unfortunately, I am unable to bound the values of $b$ that must be checked. However, numerical evidence suggests that the vast majority of primes $(b^p-1)/(b-1)$ can be found with $|b| < p$.

Comment: @DaBler I just mean, isn't it circular?

Comment: @Randall: I would say the definition is recurrent, but nor circular. On the other hand, I have also seen the definition that $p$ is prime iff $\pi(p)=\pi(p-1)+1$, where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.

Comment: @DaBler However, the definition involving the prime counting function that you mention goes downwards: that is, there are always finitely many things to check for a given prime, and there's a finite base case that you can work from. Yours goes upwards, so there are always infinitely many things to check, and there is no such base case. In particular, both the empty set and the set of all integers greater than 1 both have this property.

Comment: @user3482749 You are right. Now I see the definition in the question is surely not a definition. Sorry for that. Perhaps conjecture would be better name for it.

Comment: @DaBler I think this is a good question (as you can judge yourself by the upvotes and favorites). I hope you aren't discouraged by the few sticklers for definitions just because you didn't get all the words correct. At first, no question is well-defined. There is an easy way to make yours well-defined, so good job. My personal opinion is that definitions are for useful things. If you want to "generalize" a definition, what makes yours better than the existing one? What evidence do you have for this being easier to check, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably hopeless to prove unconditionally, but at least it is true assuming the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) saying that any non-constant polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients takes infinitely many prime values provided that

- the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive;
- $P$ is irreducible;
- $\mathrm{gcd}\{P(z)\colon z\in\mathbb Z\}=1$.

Your assertion follows readily by applying the conjecture to the polynomial $P(x)=x^{p-1}+\dotsb+x+1$.

Comment: Interesting! This is something I have missed...